# PHP Date() is showing incorrect timezone

Tags: php, date, timezone

My current time is 9:05 am. But if i print php date function like

```
<?
php echo date("h:m:s");
?>
```

it's show 4:01 pm. What's the issue. I want to show my current time with php.

And

I want to use an html iframe in my index page to show some dynamic content. I use following code, but it doesn't show my dynamic content.

```
<div id="eaturlink">
<iframe src="index.php" width="620">
<?php

$linkimgpath = 'secure/content/featurelink';

$sql_k = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feature_detail");
while ($link = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_k))
{
$linkname = $link['linkname'];
$linkimg = $link['img_name'];
$linktext = $link['linkurl'];
?>
<div class="linkimg">

<?php

echo "<a href='$linktext' target='_blank'>$linkname</a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo '<img src="' . $linkimgpath . '/' . $linkimg . '" width="125" height="85" alt="No 
Image" />  ';

?>

</div>
<?php
}   
?>
</iframe>   
</div>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: "My current time" means your local PC time or your server time?

Comment: What do you mean "my local time"?  What is the time on the server that you are running this code?

Comment: Well @emailleninl, Yes it's my PC time. I test it on my local server eg:locahost.

Comment: In php to get hours:minutes:seconds it's `date("h:i:s")` because m stands for month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [date_default_timezone_set();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and passing in the [appropriate timezone identifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) for your local timezone.

As for your second question, that is.. well, a separate question and therefore should be its own question on SO. I answered the date question as the title on this question was referring to date :-)

The `<iframe>` will load whatever page you specify per `src=`. The dynamic content you output directly there will only be used as fallback. Put your image output code in a separate script, and reference that per `<iframe src=images.php>`.

@UmmeHabibaKanta the text/data inbetween  and  is used as HTML to be displayed/rendered by the browser in the event that the browser does not support the iframe tag, otherwise it's completely ignored by the browser. If you want to display something in an iframe, you would put it on an another file and use something like `<iframe src="path/to/that/file/you/just/created.php">Sorry, iframes aren't supported by your browser</iframe>` -- or as mario said you can put fallback HTML in there, which is, instead of an error message, an alternative to the iframe such as a div with content

Comment: And I had stated, it's HTML parsed by the browser in the event that the browser does not support iframes. And good team work, @mario

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to set the correct longitude and latitude in php.ini. my timezone is America/Los_angeles, so, in php.ini that section looks like this: 
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles

date.default_latitude = 34.05222

date.default_longitude = -118.24278

;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333